# Changing Date from JSON object before showing it on the screen

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

I have an app which takes data from `JSON` file,("name","date","picture_url") and show it on `RecyclerView`, but... the date is written in unix, so i need to take each "date" `JSON` Object and change it's value to proper date format, before showing it onto the screen.

So i've written something like that :

```
long dv = Long.valueOf(o.getString("date"))*1000;
Date df = new java.util.Date(dv);
String vv = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM").format(df);
o.getString("date").equals(vv);
```

In this:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            URL_DATA,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                            try {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                        for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            ListItem item = new ListItem(
                                    o.getString("name"),
                                    o.getString("date"),
                                    o.getString("picture_url"
                                    )
                            );
                            long dv = Long.valueOf(o.getString("date"))*1000;
                            Date df = new java.util.Date(dv);
                            String vv = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM").format(df);
                            o.getString("date").equals(vv);
                            listItems.add(item);
                        }
                        adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }
    );
```

But it doesn't work.
The SDK is showing no error's and im out on new ideas. 
So how can i take my "date" and change it before showing it onto the app screen ?

Comment: what is the format of date you are receiving?

Comment: where do you put the formatted date back to list item?

Comment: Can  you show the response of date you getting from api?

Comment: I think you may have misinterpreted the use of the `equals` method. It doesn’t assign anything.

Comment: The `SimpleDateFormat` class is long outmoded and notoriously troublesome. Consider adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project so you may use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), instead. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify the original `JSONObject` with your new string representation you should use the `put` method:

```
    long dv = Long.valueOf(o.getString("date"));
    YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from(
            Instant.ofEpochSecond(dv).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
    o.put("date", ym.toString());
```

At the same time this snippet demonstrates another change: use of `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, instead of the `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. This change isn’t necessary for things to work, but I recommend it. The date-time classes you use are long outmoded, and `SimpleDateFormat` in particular is notoriously troublesome. Please note that with the modern API you don’t need an explicit formatter for obtaining a string like `2017-07` since `YearMonth.toString` produces exactly such a string. Also the API converts directly from Unix time in seconds, so your reader need not wonder why you were multiplying by 1000.

### Question: Can I use `java.time` with my Java version?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on new Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310, where the modern API was first described).
- On (older) Android, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. Make sure you import the date and time classes from package `org.threeten.bp` and subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Answer (score 0):

use this method :

```
private static String getDate(long time) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
        cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
        return DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", cal).toString();
    }
```

Comment: that would do if i needed the current time but, i've got the dates from past(and there are many of them not just one) written in unix so i need to take them and convert them into normal date.

Comment: bro , use this methode to convert them 
for example 
getDate(o.getString("date")) ; 
will return the "date" with date format not with unix timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
public String timestampToFormatedString(long timeStamp,String format ){

    Date date = new Date(timeStamp);
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    return formatter.format(date);
}
```

and finally

```
String formatedDateString=timestampToFormatedString("dd-MM-yyyy",timeStamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

First : all of your answer's have good methods that I could have used, but I wasn't asking for methods because I had a proper one. Thank's anyway for th answer's.

The easiest solution what i have found was :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            long dv = Long.valueOf(o.getString("date")) * 1000L;
                            Date df = new java.util.Date(dv);
                            String vv = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(df);
                            ListItem item = new ListItem(
                                    o.getString("name")
                                    , vv
                                    , o.getString("picture_url")

                            );
                            listItems.add(item);
```

I had my a tiny part of my code misunderstood so i needed to put this code a few lines back and change one line.